# Creating form fields on certain table rows that echo php values

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, html-table

I have a page that displays about 12 tables that are filled from database values. These values correspond with a single record but some of these fields are based off of queries I'm making so that if something's wrong in the query, it will display red text.

I'm only doing this for a few different fields but I want an option to edit and fix those fields and then save them to the database with an UPDATE.

Basically, I don't want to wrap the whole page in a form since only a few fields in a few of the tables will need to be editable. Is there a way to do this so that I can edit only the few fields that need to be fixed?

Here's a table as example:

```
<div class="testResults" style=" width: 30%; clear:both; float: left;">
<!--Test Results Table-->
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Test Results</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Tested Within AWWA Standards</td>
<td><? echo $row['standards'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Meter Failed on Low Side</td>
<td><? echo $row['lowFail'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Meter Failed on High Side</td>
<td><? echo $row['highFail'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Meter Failed Low and High Side</td>
<td><? echo $row['bothFail'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Unable To Test</td>
<td><? echo $row['unableTest'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, for example, say I want to edit the data for just standards row and lowFail row.

I know once this is done I'll need to have a submit button that attaches to a query to update with the input name, but right NOw i'm trying to find the best way to edit.

Is it easiest to just wrap the whole page in a form and just create the few inputs where I need?